# Заполнить матрицу ЛП, от центра по спирали: вниз - влево - вверх - вправо c++

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы, матрицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#define N 9

int main()
{
int spiral[N][N];
int i, j, k, edge, num = N * N;
for (k = 0; k < N / 2; k++) //слои
{

    edge = N - 1 - k;
    for (i = edge; i > k; i--, num--)
        spiral[i][k] = num;

    for (j = k; j < edge; j++, num--)
        spiral[k][j] = num;

    for (i = k; i < edge; i++, num--)
        spiral[i][edge] = num;

    for (j = edge; j > k; j--, num--)
        spiral[edge][j] = num;

}
if (N % 2) //если N-нечетное дополнить центральным элементом
    spiral[N / 2][N / 2] = num;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        printf("%6d", spiral[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");

}

return 0;
}
```

Нужно немного изменить код. Прошу помочь разобраться.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Непонятно в чем именно вопрос .. (используйте кнопку "править")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените вывод на

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (j = N-1; j >= 0; j--) {
        printf("%6d", spiral[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Как я понимаю, это всё, что вам нужно...