Заполнение квадратной матрицы по спирали по часовой стрелке от центра
Я знаю, что решения задачи есть, но хотелось написать свой код.
Суть: есть файл с квадратной матрицей нечетной размерности, надо написать код, который ее считывает и заполняет своими же значениями по спирали, а потом находит наибольший элемент. Это все на СИ, то есть без применения векторов.
Функцию с нахождением наибольшего элемента пока не трогал, так как основная часть не работает. Программа компилируется, выводит на экран матрицу, которую считал из файла, но функция заполнения по спирали не работает. Скажите, в чем проблема?
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 7

float spiral(double matrix[N][N]) {
    FILE* file2 = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    if (!file2)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    double M[N][N];
    size_t i, j;
    for (int k = 0; k < N / 2; k++) {
    //while (k < N / 2) {
        for (j = N / 2 - k; i = N / 2 + k; j < N / 2 + k && j++) 
            M[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
        for (i = N / 2 + k; i > N / 2 - k; i--) 
            M[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
        for (j = N / 2 + k; j > N / 2 - k; j--) 
            M[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
        for (i = N / 2 - k; i < N / 2 + k; i++) 
            M[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
        printf("%lf ", M[i][j]);
        fprintf(file2, "%lf ", M[i][j]);
    }
    fclose(file2);

double main(int argc, char** argv) {
    double matrix1[N][N];
    size_t i, j;
    FILE* file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (!file)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    for (i = 0; i < N && !feof(file); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N && !feof(file); j++) {
            fscanf(file, "%lf", &matrix1[i][j]);
            printf("%lf ", matrix1[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    fclose(file);
    return spiral(matrix1);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
} 


https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8

я писал в посте, что знаю, что есть решения. вопрос был что не так именно в моем коде.

Да вообще непонятно, что ваш код делает. Например, зачем вы создаете матрицу M, идентичную передаваемой в функцию? У вас же все присваивания M[i][j] = matrix[i][j]... Понимаете, проще написать заново, чем разбираться. Или куда должна идти спираль, выходя из центра?

потому что смысл в том, чтобы сделать точно такую же матрицу, но заполняющуюся по спирали. такое вот задание. а что код должен делать - написано прямо в посте. программа нормально работает до момента открытия output.txt и теряется где-то в цикле.

я прямо в заголовке написал: спираль должна идти по часовой стрелке. то есть от центрального элемента влево - вниз - наверх - направо.

точно такую же матрицу, но заполняющуюся по спирали - вы и делаете точно такую же, а не по спирали. Может, вы и выполняете присваивания по спирали, не знаю, но то, что матрица M полностью совпадает с переданной (разве что в коде есть ошибки и какие-то элементы оказываются пропущены), а не ее спиральным собратом, так сказать - это точно. Впрочем, одного цикла for (j = N / 2 - k; i = N / 2 + k; j < N / 2 + k && j++) достаточно, чтоб ничего не работало. У него же условие всегда истинно, нет? :) Подумайте немного, вспомните, как работает цикл for...

Где в вопросе хоть одно слово "влево"? а "по часовой стрелке из центра" - таких спиралей 4.

j же должен доходить до N/2-1 включительно и завершаться.

"по спирали по часовой стрелке" - буквально заполнение влево.

Еще раз - посмотрите, как работает цикл for. Если вы сами поймаете ошибку, то запомните ее. По часовой стрелке никакого "влево" не подразумевает. Нарисуйте, поверните получившуюся картинку на 90-180-270 градусов и скажите - это что, не "по часовой из центра"?

не знаю, я играю в ммо, у нас по часовой стрелке = влево. первый раз вижу, чтобы кого-то это смущало

"влево - вниз - наверх - направо" - это как, какя линия??? Если по часовой, то д. б. "вправо - вниз - влево - вверх"

@rotabor А почему не "вверх-вправо-вниз-влево"? Или "вниз-влево-вверх-вправо"?

С for разобрались? Жирнейший намек: for(инициализация; УСЛОВИЕ; действие)...

цикл я уже починил, но лажа все равно выводится.

@Harry просто у автора сначала шаг в сторону.

Ну не хочется переписывать — посмотрите сами: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1349077/195342  Доверните так, чтоб шло не вниз сначала, а влево, вот и готовое решение...

ааа, ого, тут почти так же как у меня. спасибо!

Фу, четыре вложенных цикла...

Ну хочется поделиться своим решением, правда, на c#:
using System;
class Program{
    static void Main(){
        string of, bl;
        int N, root, rows, columns, zR, zC, dR = 0, dC = 1;
        Console.Write("Enter a natural number: ");
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out N) | N < 1) {
            Console.WriteLine("Not a natural number");
        }
        { int i = N.ToString().Length + 1;
            of = "{0," + i + "}";
            bl = new String(' ', i); }
        rows = columns = root = (int)Math.Sqrt(N);
        if (N > root * root) columns++; zC = (columns - 1) / 2;
        if (N > root * root + root) rows++; zR = (rows - 1) / 2;
        var sp = new int[rows, columns];
        for (int i = 1, k = 1, l = 0; i <= N; i++) {
            sp[zR, zC] = i; zR += dR; zC += dC; l++;
            if (l == k){
                if (dC == 0) {k++; dC = 0 - dR; dR = 0;}
                else {dR = dC; dC = 0;}
                l = 0;
            }
        }
        // вывод результата
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) 
                if (sp[i, j] == 0) Console.Write(bl); else Console.Write(of, sp[i, j]);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

-->

Enter a natural number: 100
  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82
  72  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  83
  71  42  21  22  23  24  25  26  51  84
  70  41  20   7   8   9  10  27  52  85
  69  40  19   6   1   2  11  28  53  86
  68  39  18   5   4   3  12  29  54  87
  67  38  17  16  15  14  13  30  55  88
  66  37  36  35  34  33  32  31  56  89
  65  64  63  62  61  60  59  58  57  90
 100  99  98  97  96  95  94  93  92  91


Однопроходный алгоритм с минимальным количеством условных операторов.
